# Combining Left & Right Join in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, full-outer-join

I am joining 2 tables -tbl1 and tbl2. Left join give all data from tbl1 which is in tbl2 or only on tbl1. Right join gives data from tbl2 which is don't exists in tbl1.

I want to combine both results.

What is the best way to do this so that I get all data from tbl1 and tbl2?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only you can do that is by using `UNION`. MySQL doesn't support `FULL JOIN`just like in MSSQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 t1 
       LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2
          ON t1.col = t2.col
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 t1 
       RIGHT JOIN tbl2 t2 
          ON t1.col>= t2.<col
```

**[SEE HERE: Simulating FULL JOIN in MYSQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/)**

By the way, `UNION` has optional keyword `ALL`,when the `ALL` is omitted, `UNION` automatically selects `DISTINCT` rows from the resultset.

EXAMLE:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   tableA
```

this can result duplicates rows

```
ColA    ColB
==================
1       John
2       Jade
2       Jade
3       Hello
```

BUT if you omit the word `ALL`

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableA
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   tableA
```

this can result distinct rows only

```
ColA    ColB
==================
1       John
2       Jade
3       Hello
```

Answer (score 10):

What you want is `FULL JOIN`

> `LEFT JOIN` + `RIGHT JOIN` = `FULL JOIN`

So try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl1
RIGHT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
```

The `UNION` clause combines the results of two SQL queries into a single table of all matching rows.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that can be easily extended if you have a full join of more than 2 tables:

```
SELECT t1*, t2.* 
FROM 
    ( SELECT col
      FROM tbl1
    UNION
      SELECT col
      FROM tbl2
    ) AS d
  LEFT JOIN tbl1 AS t1 
    ON t1.col = d.col
  LEFT JOIN tbl2 AS t2
    ON t2.col = d.col ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use FULL OUTER JOIN, But mysql doesnt support it.. You could do this for getting the result:

```
 SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 t1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2
ON t1.<col> = t2.<col>
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 t1 RIGHT JOIN tbl2 t2 
ON t1.<col>= t2.<col>
```